# How to use Material Design Components from Material.io in Nuxt.js

Tags: material-design, nuxt.js

i got really stuck and didn't find any relative search about my problem.
i wanna use material design components in my nuxt project but it not work properly.
for example i wanna use the [Outlined Text](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/text-field/#outlined-text) , installed the component via npm, add cdn to my nuxt head (because i couldn't creat a scss file, it gave me error, so help on this part too) and the input style is ok but not the script part. so added "JavaScript instantiation" section codes and the second line gives me the following error: 
ReferenceError
document is not defined

so i really appreciate and be thankful if some one help me. and i know about https://vuematerial.io/ but it has two problem, first don't have all the components and second it's really hard to change it's style (at least i couldn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make SCSS work , you need to to download extra package for it

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader
```

Also `ReferenceError document is not defined` its very common beginner gotcha.

You need to wrap your code in this if statement to check that you are on the client side. I guess you have put your code into `created()` or `mounted()`. Both gets executed 2 times, once on the server side, and then on client side. The error appears when it runs on the server side, because there is no window, document or any browser stuff on the server, so you need to check:

```
if(process.client) {
   //do stuff on client side, document is defined here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Vuetify? Vuetify is a Vue UI Library with beautifully handcrafted Material Components.